# Where the javascript is compiled using "pub serve"? (how to package all artifacts of a dart web application ?)

Tags: dart, dart-pub

By default "pub serve" command, compile dart code to javascript code and serve it through http. Where those javascript files are compiled ?

My real goal is to package easily all artifacts (.dart,.js, assets) of a dart web application to be able to deploy theme through another server (e.i. httpd apache).

(i'm using pub 1.5.3)

Comment: Added an issue : https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pub serve` calls the `$dart2js` transformer internally.

If you need the output for deployment you use `pub build` instead of `pub serve`.
`pub build` creates a `build/web` output directory ready to use for deployment.